# How to print out query of tuples stored in a list on HTML page

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to print out some tuples I have stored in a list however I keep getting blank tables. Here is some of my code:

`__init__.py`:

```
def view_jobs():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DBNAME)
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute('SELECT * FROM Companies, Job WHERE Companies.cid = Job.cid')

    rows = c.fetchall()

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return rows
```

`web_page.py`:

```
@app.route('/Student/Search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def studentSearch():
    table = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('studentsearch.html')
    else: 
        table = adb.view_jobs()
        print table
        return render_template('studentsearch.html', table=table)
```

`studentsearch.html:`

```
<tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>Company E-mail</th>
                    <th>Internship Position</th>
                    <th>Internship Description</th>

                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                  {% for row in table %}
                    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.job_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.job_description}}</td>
                  {% endfor %}
                  </tr>
```

when I print to console I get the appropriate data but when I run this I get a site with no data output. The only other experience I have with this is with Django and that seemed to hold the attribute names in place when I passed the array to the HTML but I probably I was probably using something more sophisticated for my queries... Not sure if there is anything specific with flask that I am missing.

I'm thinking the error lies with how I'm passing `table` but I'm not sure what the best way to do that is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
<tr>
    {% for row in table %}
       <td>{{row.name}}</td> # You are trying to access a tuple attribute like a dictionary 
       <td>{{row.email}}</td> # Same here and below
       <td>{{row.job_type}}</td>
       <td>{{row.job_description}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Changes you can do is

**Convert query :**

```
c.execute('SELECT name, email, job_type, job_description FROM Companies, Job WHERE Companies.cid = Job.cid')
```

Then in the `studentsearch.html`

**Change:**

```
<tr>
    {% for row in table %}
       <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
       <td>{{row[1]}}</td> 
       <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
       <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
```